# make a unique hash out of two strings

Tags: algorithm, scala

Can anyone think of a way to make a unique hash out of two strings? Something that ensures:

`hash(string1,string2) = hash(string2,string1).`

I can always store the same reference under two different values in my map, but I thought: There must be a better way...

Comment: Compare them, and use the smaller as first string, the bigger as second string. Maybe you should explain, why you want such a behaviour.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another way is to hash both strings and xor the results. Since xor is commutative, the order doesn't matter. If the hashes are equal, don't xor them to avoid collisions with other pairs of identical strings.

Comment: Seems right to me, every string I'm working with is unique by the way.

Comment: If that's guaranteed, you don't even need to check whether the hashes are the same.

Comment: Although ordering would also work, this is of course much more beautiful from a theoretical CS perspective ;)

Comment: Having different strings doesn't guaranty you that your hashes will be different in theory.

Comment: @ChrisJamesC: So then you get a hash of zero whenever the two strings happen to have the same hash. That's not a problem.

Comment: @KimStebel your point is good. After it only depends on the behavior needed for the function.

Answer (score 9):

Do you want to be fast, or do you want to be good?  Any symmetric operation on the individual hash codes will produce what you want; `+`, `*`, and `^` are all decent choices; `^` produces 0 if the two are the same, so you generally need an `if` to catch that; `+` is more likely to generate collisions than `*` but both are not so great given that the intrinsic `hashCode` method on `String` is pretty lousy:

```
scala> "BB".hashCode == "Aa".hashCode  // Seriously?!
res40: Boolean = true
```

If you want your strings to not collide so much, use `scala.util.MurmurHash.stringHash` on the strings (2.9; `scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash.stringHash` in 2.10), and then one of the above methods.

Comment: I didn't understand the first line, do you mean `hash(a) + hash(b)` will produce what OP wants? (ie. `hash(a) + hash(b) == hash(b) + hash(a)`)

Answer (score 8):

Well you could try "ordering" both strings before hashing them, so that any pair of strings will always be processed in the same order.

Comment: Haha this is genius!

Answer (score 7):

Check to see if they're in alphabetical order and swap them if they're not before concatenating them and hashing the result.